# Can a GFCI combo and a switch be independently connected to a light and a fan using 14/3 wire?

Tags: wiring, lighting, switch, gfci, fans

The box on the left in the diagram is a dimmer switch and the box on the right is a GFCI combo switch. The ground wiring is absent from the diagram. How can this wiring be completed to connect the fan and light independently?

[image: Wiring diagram]

Comment: Do you want GFCI protection for the light and fan?  Why are there three terminals on the dimmer?  If the dimmer is a 3-way, which terminal is common (black)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## With GFCI Protection of Devices

If you want to provide GFCI protection of the fixture, you'd feed the switches from the LOAD side of the GFCI device.

[image: Circuit with GFCI protection]

## Without GFCI Protection of Devices

If you don't want to provide GFCI protection to the devices, you'd feed the switches from the incoming feeder.

[image: Circuit without GFCI protection]

<sub>***NOTE:** I've labeled one of the dimmer terminals as "C" (common), as it looks like you might have a 3-way dimmer. In this case the "C" terminal will be an odd color (likely black), while the other two will be the same color (brass). Unless of course the third terminal in your diagram is green (ground), in which case you should ignore this note and connect the grounding conductor to the green terminal.*</sub>